How to add Link Annotation to tag tree with PDFKit?
I'm using PDFKit and Node.js/Javascript to dynamically generate a PDF file.
The PDF should be fully accessible, but there are errors with the accessibility of links and annotations.
The link is properly displayed and has the proper Link tag, but the annotation object isn't linked to the tag tree.
This is how the tag tree should look like, but the marked "Link Annotation" is missing.
This is how I generate my links:
const linkEl = doc.struct('Link',{title: link, actual: link, name: link}, () => {
      doc.text(link, {continued: true, link:link, title: link, actual: link});
  });
elem.add(linkEl);     //elem = mainStruct of the document

I also tried to generate the link with doc.link(doc.x + widthText, doc.y, widthLink, height, link);, but it didn't help.
Is there a way to make links accessible with PDFKit or a work around without manually fixing it afterwards?
